# Generate xml php code problem

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml

I am using a php script to generate an xml from my magento 1.9 to a comparison engine.
I have a field in the engine called mpn which need to be filled from my product's SKUs

```
$aData['id']=$iProduct;
$aData['mpn']=mb_substr($oProduct->getSku(),0,99,'UTF-8');
```

First line gives the product id and second the mpn field.

Now because of a problem I want to create the sku for my store only and give other SKUs to engine. The code must work only if new attribute is filled. If it not sku will pass to engine. So I created a new attribute with code

> new_mpn

And I filled in the code just above this:

```
$aData['mpn']=mb_substr($oProduct->getSku(),0,99,'UTF-8');
```

this:

```
if($oProduct->getNewMpn()!=''){$aData['mpn'] = @mb_substr($oProduct->getNewMpn(), 0, 99, 'UTF-8');}
```

But this don't work. I don't get the products.

Can anyone help?